# Passing separate information into a hash render

Tags: reactjs

So say I've got a hash of objects that I want to render in my parent's render:

```js
renderChild: function(child) {
  return (
    <Child key={child}/>
  );
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(hashObj).map(this.renderChild)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I've also got a variable I want to send along to this renderChild.

Would the best way to go about this is setting a state, or can I send a prop down through to the `this.renderChild` somehow through the map render?

Something along the lines of (which is wrong because I know it doesn't work): `{Object.keys(hashObj).map(this.renderChild, someVariable)}`

I would like to send it via a prop within the map, so I don't have to have a state to keep track of.

Was wondering if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an anonymous function that *calls* `this.renderChild` instead of a direct reference to it. Don't forget to make sure `map` uses the right value for `this`:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(hashObj).map(function(item) {
        return this.renderChild(someVariable);
      }, this)}
    </div>
  );
}
```